# Werbung für diese Seite

Tags: discussion

> Advertise this site!

Will nicht irgendwer ein bißchen Werbung machen?

> Does anyone want to advertise this site?

Comment: I actually find it a bit embarrassing to show this site to German students of linguistics or Germanistics due to the English UI and crude design. I'm trying with the German-learners, though.

Comment: @Tim Really? What makes you think that German students care especially about the interface and design?

Comment: @thei: The difference is not between German/non-German, but between amateurs/professionals. I have the feeling that professionals want something more well-polished to spend their time on (unless they came from SO and know SE). Of course, that's just my interpretation.

Comment: @TimN And what should we do to improve the content? (Except quoting german proverbs) ;-)

Comment: @Markus: No complaints at all about the content :) I suppose these things are hard to fix since we're just a beta, and there's a lot of betas around.

Comment: @Tim I respectfully disagree--any (potentially active) professional user would look at the content and realise the site has value.