# Is it OK to promote linguistics.stackexchange.com here?

Tags: discussion

Linguistics.se is nearing 100 % commitment (currently only 18 more people needed). Is it acceptable to bring this to the attention of people here, or is that considered spamming? I was hoping speakers of German might be interested, since the sites will be closely related:

[Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics)

Comment: It's nice of you to ask while posting the link :)

Comment: Heh. Yeah. *May I promote <shady product here> on this site or is that considered spamming?* ;)

Comment: @TimN: I plead guilty! Though I was also genuinely interested in whether or not this spamming was appreciated, and that would have been hard without mentioning which specific proposal I had in mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imho it should always be OK if its likely that some questions get migrated from proposal to proposal. We already had questions here which got closed or would better fit linguistics.

I already asked [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/visits-per-day-should-we-be-worried/250#250) to commit to other proposals related to language.

I would recommend to place a link on all proposals/Betas related to language in each others sidebar on the main page, so we build a smaller language-network on SE and profitate a bit from the highly frequented english.SE. People dont look on and on what new Betas there are, or mainly frequent their top 3 sites and forget. I dont look very often on the main site stackexchange.com, too overloaded to me...

Comment: OK thanks, I agree. And putting the links in a sidebar would be an excellent idea!