# What must be done to promote our site?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the current state http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage I find that the most annoying number is the low number of only currently 138 users with 200+ rep.

Second comes the number of questions and third the number of visits.

On the other side, is it a real problem to stay a long time in beta and let things mature?

Comment: If there are more questions there is also more rep to go around, so this is the only point that is actually important.

Comment: See also: [When will our site graduate from beta?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/347/1859)

Answer (score 4):

We had similar question already

[Visits per day -- should we be worried?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/618)

I dont think you have to worry that this site get closed. SE team knows, that user number will grow with ongoing time.

Interesting to compare

http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=newengagedusers&expand=true
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage

So imho our stats look OKish to me

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage

Spanish proposal will soon start and probably make SE as a language site much more popular, Japanese, French, German are likely still minorities in the language spectrum of SE users.

good opportunity to advertize

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21061/latin-language-usage

one more time ;) Please vote questinos with less than 10 votes!

Comment: -1 for OKisch. Just using OK is OK. :)